# Eventos do mouse (ao passar em um elemento x) Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, lógica, eventos-do-mouse

Bem, estou com problemas com o mouseenter().
ele só dispara o evento se eu clicar, preciso que ao passar dentro de um elemento(div) ele dispare o evento.

Como estou fazendo:

```
                        $('#<?php echo $x?>').mouseenter(function(){
                            $('#<?php echo $x?>').popover('show');
                        });
```

Quando eu clico dispara,mais na verdade preciso que ele dispare ao passar o mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é que você utiliza o método [`mouseover`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) na verdade, neste caso lá no seu `PHP` ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
$('#<?php echo $x?>').mouseover(function(){
    $('#<?php echo $x?>').popover('show');
});
```

Para ter certeza que o evento está sendo atrelado corretamente você pode inserir um alerta no item para que uma mensagem seja disparada na tela:

```
$('#<?php echo $x?>').mouseover(function(){
    $('#<?php echo $x?>').popover('show');
    alert("Mouse sobre o elemento: <?php echo $x?>"));
});
```

Caso tenha mais dificuldades, poste na sua pergunta o conteúdo final do seu `html` e `js`, pois se dessa foram ainda não funcionar, o problema provavelmente passará a ser outro.

Answer (score 0):

O evento que você quer é o `.mouseover()`.

Qualquer coisa de uma olhada na documentação dele, [link](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)